# Pip install systemd on Unix

Tags: unix, installation, pip, systemd

What are some alternatives to usbrip for mac detection of a rubber ducky? Or is there a way to run usbrip in a virtual environment that will still get a full historical log?

Comment: It seems you are on MacOS, systemd is sort of a Linux thing only. The MacOS alternative is called launchd (https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-use-launchd-to-run-services-in-macos-b972ed1e352). Not sure about alternatives or how to get it working though.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/usbrip/#description: Simple CLI forensics tool for tracking USB device artifacts (history of USB events) on **GNU/Linux**. No way on MacOS X.